sum of elements of $\mathbb{F}_{17}$ in terms of power of primitive element
Consider the field $\mathbb{F}_{17}$. Then $3$ is a primitive element of $\mathbb{F}_{17}$. Now we have $\hspace{1cm}$
$ 3^2+3^4=3^5\\ 3^2+3^6=3^9\\ 3^2+3^{14}=3^7 \\ 3^{2}+3^{16}=3^3.$
That is for $3^2$  there are exactly $4$ other even powers of 3 such that their sum is a odd power. Infact for all even powers of $3$ there are exactly $4$ other even powers of $3$ such that their sum is a odd power of $3$. Can we guess the resultant power of $3$ without explicitly calculating it? I don't want the exact power just want to know if it is even or odd or how many times it is even or odd. I tried using Zech logarithm but couldn't conclude anything.

So you want to compute the Legendre symbol $\left(\frac{9+x^2}{17}\right)$.

Parity of exponents of powers of primitive roots has no relevance because even and odd exponents can give both "even" and "odd" classes (parity is not valid notion for $\mathbb F_p$). Such a result would be useful if it were  valid for a large class of $\mathbb F_p$. However this seems not possible to obtain.

I can answer how many times $3^2+3^{2n}$ is an even power of $3$, where $0\le n<16$.
First of all, $3^n$ runs over all elements of $\mathbb F_{17}^\times$ since $3$ is a primitive root, so you are equivalently asking how many times $9+x^2$ is an even power of $3$, where $x\in\mathbb F_{17}^\times$. Moreover, $9+x^2$ being an even power of $3$ is equivalent to the existence of a $y\in\mathbb F_{17}^\times$ such that $9+x^2=y^2$.
Solutions to $9+x^2=y^2$ are given by $(x,y)=(\frac32a-\frac 3{2a},\frac32a+\frac3{2a})$ for $a\in\mathbb F_{17}^\times$.
Thus, you are asking for the number of $a\in\mathbb F_{17}^\times$ such that $\frac32a-\frac3{2a}\ne0$ and $\frac32a+\frac3{2a}\ne0$. This is saying $a^2\ne\pm1$, i.e., $a\ne \pm1,\pm4$. Thus this gives $16-4=12$ possiblities for $a$. But additionally, $a$ and $-1/a$ give the same value of $x$, so in fact there are $12/2=6$ possiblities for $x$ such that $3^2+x^2$ is an even power of $3$.
The above method generalizes to arbitrary primitive roots in $\mathbb F_p^\times$.

Can you please explain why we are taking $a$ such that $x$ and $y$ are non zero? Also for any other prime for which $3$ is a primitive root, will always four values of $a$ be excluded (since we are basically finding elements of order 1,2 and 4 in a cyclic group)?

Let $\alpha$ be a primitive element of $\Bbb F_{17}$. You are essentially asking how many squares $x^2$ there are in $\Bbb F_{17}$ such that $\alpha^2(1+x^2)$ is a non-square, i.e. such that $1+x^2$ is a non-square.
The eight non-zero squares in $\Bbb F_{17}$ are
$$\pm1,\pm2,\pm4,\pm8$$ hence the values of $1+x^2$ are
$$2,0,3,-1,5,-3,-8,-7.$$
Exactly four of them are non-squares.
We could have avoided to list them, by the following reasoning: the ordered pairs $(x,y)\in\Bbb F_{17}^2$
such that $1+x^2=y^2$ are in bijection with $\Bbb F_{17}^\times$ (by $z\mapsto(
2^{-1}(z-z^{-1}),2^{-1}(z+z^{-1}))$ hence there are $16$ such pairs. They generally go by groups of four, $(\pm x,\pm y)$, which reduce to two if either $x$ or $y$ is zero. The number $n$ of corresponding pairs $(x^2,y^2)$ is therefore such that $16=2+2+4(n-2)$, i.e. $n=5$. So, there are five squares $x^2$ (including $0$) such that $1+x^2$ is a square. For the remaining  four squares $x^2$, $1+x^2$ is not a square.
